# Can I use acts_as_list to create multiple lists within one column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I'm trying to add `acts_as_list` to an existing `playlists` table in my database, which stores any playlists that my users might have created. The goal is to allow users to sort their own playlists.

This migration will set a default position for the playlists in the table, but the position will be set in a global context (for example, the `position` column will be ordered 1-500 for a table with 500 playlists in it):

```
class AddPositionToPlaylistsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column  :playlists, :position, :integer
    Playlist.reset_column_information
    playlist = Playlist.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC")

    playlist.each_with_index do |p, i|
      p.position = i+1
      p.save
    end

  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :playlists, :position
  end
end
```

This order would be problematic, because moving an item's position from 500 to 499 wouldn't necessarily reflect any change from the user's perspective (as they might have playlists that have a `position` of 50, 70, 100, and 500).

Instead, I want to set a position for each playlist in the table in a per-user context (for example, presuming each user has 5 playlists, the `position` column would have multiple instances of playlists ordered 1-5 for each user).

Is this possible, and if so, how would I modify my migration to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating your playlists position, you only take the user's playlists into account. So you should do it from the beginning. In your migration's `up`-method you could get all playlists per user and then increase the index like you did:

```
#....
User.all.each do |user|
  user_playlists = user.playlists(:order => "created_at ASC")

  user_playlists.each_with_index do |p, i|
    p.position = i+1
    p.save
  end
end
```